# How do I remove the leading dot in OWIN cookie domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

We´re creating an MVC web application with 2 different parts:

- domain.com is the primary site
- admin.domain.com is the administration part of the site

Both sites have their own set of user - and if a user logs into domain.com, then he shouldn't be authenticated on the admin site - and vice versa.

I've setup the OWIN provider in Startup.cs for both sites:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            CookieDomain = "domain.com"
        });
```

And a similar in the admin project with the CookieDomain set to "admin.domain.com".

However - when I deploy this and log into domain.com, then the ".AspNetApplicationCookie" created belongs to the domain ".domain.com" (notice the dot) - which in terms means that any user that logs into domain.com is also authenticated on all sub-domains (including admin.domain.com). This is NOT what I want.

Does any of you guys know why the CookieDomain in my Startup.cs is ignored? This is a major issue for our application.

I can find lot's of posts about sharing authentication across sub-domains - but I specifically don't wanna do this. Each cookie must belong to the exact domain specified in my CookieComain property.

Any input would be much appreciated :)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So it seems that this is only an issue when using Chrome or Firefox. If I log in using IE then the cookie domain is set to the expected value. 
Have any of you guys experienced this? And perhaps maybe have a fix for it?

Comment: I think you would need to have domain.com redirect to something like nonadmin.domain.com and authenticate against that instead.

Comment: I thought about that too - but shouldn't it be possible to create an authentication cookie for JUST the primary domain (and not sub-domains)?

Comment: Someone may be able to prove me wrong, but I don't think it works that way.